# Does Sitecore's Web Forms For Marketers module offer a way for email subscribers to manage subscriptions?

Tags: sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers

Has anybody had luck using Sitecore's Web Forms For Marketers to manage email subscriptions? I am looking for a solution to allow subscribers a way to opt-out of an email list that they're already subscribed to.

Also, I need to offer them a way to manage multiple subscriptions on one page. Ultimately, they'd just be managing which list/database they're in.

(Ideally, I usually prefer that my clients use a third party email marketing platform, but unfortunately - this is not the case here.)

Comment: Does this mean your client is using SC ECM? So you want a form to allow people to opt out of the SC ECM?

Answer (score 0):

You can check here : 
http://sdn.sitecore.net/Products/ECM.aspx Email Campaigner has a form ascx for subscribers .
It can be used on multisites solutions